# Receive multiple files in java app via arguments

Tags: java, windows, registry

I want to receive multiple selected files in explorer and send them to my app via command line arguments. If it will one file, in registry I can write:

```
java -jar myapp.jar "%1"
```

In this case, of course, all selected files would be opened in separate instances of app.
Can I receive multiple files in one instance? And what I have to write instead of "%1" to reach my goal?

Comment: May be it is just impossible? I seleсt some files and explorer execute command for each file. I dont know can I change behaviour of explorer

Comment: Until I decided to use sockets. First instance of app creates server and the rest connects to first.
Windows is evil :(